# iOS Buttons Conflicting with Edge Gestures on Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uigesturerecognizer

I have buttons on my custom keyboard on the left and right side of the screen that have .touchdown actions. When I click on them they don't register the .touchdown right away and seem to be waiting to see if there is a swipe gesture. I tried using code to defer the edge gestures but in iOS 13 this doesn't seem to do the trick. Does anyone have a solution for how to get the buttons on the edge perform .touchdown action immediately when clicked?

```
override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return [.left, .bottom, .right]
}
```

I also tried using the point function in a custom button class but that only makes it highlight but still doesn't perform the action right away.

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let inside = super.point(inside: point, with: event)

    if inside && !isHighlighted && event?.type == .touches {
        isHighlighted = inside
    }

    return bounds.insetBy(dx: -2.7, dy: -12).contains(point)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let window = view.window,
        let recognizers = window.gestureRecognizers {
        recognizers.forEach { r in
            r.delaysTouchesBegan = false
            r.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            r.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```